# How to create a custom transverse mercator projection?

Tags: python, shapefile, shapely, geopandas, coordinate-system

I'm working on a script that performs some simple geometric manipulations such as buffering vector data using shapely or geopandas. The input (i.e. original) shapefile could be geographically located anywhere on Earth and be in any spatial reference system. I need to ensure the coordinate system is standardized and projected prior to running the geometric operations because preserving distance is important to my analysis.

How can I create a custom transverse mercator projected coordinate system using geopandas and/or shapely?

The following is what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
import geopandas as gpd

in_shp = r'C:\path\to\input_shapefile.shp'
out_shp = r'C:\path\to\output_shapefile.shp'

# GeoPandas
geometry = gpd.read_file(in_shp)

# Project to a custom transverse mercator projected coordinate system
sr = {'a custom transverse mercator proj4 string'} # Here's the main issue
projected_geometry = geometry.to_crs(sr)

# Buffer 100m
buffered_geometry = projected_geometry.buffer(100)

# Convert to WGS84
final_product = buffered_geometry.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

# Write to disk
final_product.to_file(out_shp)
```

Comment: Is the issue the required proj4 params, or how to apply it in geopandas? In the [geopandas docs](http://geopandas.org/projections.html) it looks like you should be able to throw in any proj4 string (or dict of proj4 parameters).

Comment: @om_henners Essentially how to construct the correct proj4 params. Applying it in GeoPandas should be as simple as `geoseries.to_crs(proj4string)`, I believe.

Comment: Does this help: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/proj4-definition-for-transverse-mercator-projection-from-RegCM3-model-for-North-America-td3841682.html ?